# Is there property right of son of a divorced wife in Islam?

Tags: talaq, property

Is there property right of son of a divorced wife and if so, can he enjoy the equal rights to the property of his father as compared to the son of a married wife?

Comment: Are you asking about inheritance?

Comment: @UmH yeah, ofcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All biological sons of the father receive an equal share of the inheritance, regardless of whether their mother is divorced or deceased. The status of the mother only effects her share, not that of the children.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Where can I get this reference,i.e, is it according to the Quran or the Hadith?